# Magento - show a single product in homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

how to show a single product in homepage of Magento, I want to show exactly the product name, image and price.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:
[Adding Products To The Home Page Of Magento](http://www.mywebtronics.com/adding-products-to-the-home-page-of-magento/)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to add that product to a category and display that category on the homepage by going to CMS - Manage Pages, select Home Page from the list of pages and add

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

where category_id="8" is the category's id (thisid is displayed on the category page in Magento's admin)

Comment: Thanks a lot creativityhurts, 
I know this solution... I don't know if there is another one for only one product...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to do a redirectmatch in the htaccess to your preferred product and then to give that product something like 'buynow' or 'welcome.html' as the URL code on it's product page settings.